# Hive query log - aggregated logs per query

Tags: performance, logging, hive

Where does Hive store the query logs? There is a property hive.querylog.location from the [Getting Started page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted). This seems to suggest each hive node/client will store the logs in this location. Is there a location where all of these aggregated per query?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Hive stores its logs in `/tmp/currentuser` location. When the Hive shell is invoked using the `hive` command at the Unix/Linux prompt, Hive displays the location of the log using the line `Hive history file=location of the log` before the Hive prompt is displayed. Example output is shown below:

`[root@localhost root]# hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.4.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

Hive history file=/tmp/root/hive_job_log_46a27ee2-7ac1-43f5-a66b-20d6ea982421_849420221.txt

hive>`

If a Hive query generates MapReduce jobs, those logs can be viewed through the JobTracker page which is accessible via the browser.
The path to the logs is:
`Mapper logs: Job Tracker Page -> Completed Jobs -> Jobid -> map -> task id -> Task Logs

Reducer logs: Job Tracker Page -> Completed Jobs -> Jobid -> reduce -> task id -> Task Logs`

Answer (score 0):

Execute the query with below command

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=DEBUG -e "<query>"

OR

hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=DEBUG -f <hql-file>
```

It will create a log file in logs folder. Make sure that the logs folder exist in current directory.